# Amazon SES and Hotmail spam

Tags: google-apps, hotmail, amazon-ses, spf, dkim

I configured an email address with google apps for my company. When I send messages from Gmail to address@hotmail.com the message is received correctly in the inbox folder.

When I moved to Amazon SES, I configured correctly SPF and DKIM so that it may work fine. The big problem is that when I send from SES emails go allways into the spam folder!!!

This is the hotmail header of a message that is falled into the spam folder:

```
x-store-info:CnuewmGKkJzNjuOw4Ko28wB3rXpWYbsxTq8bIGVpexou/aH5YlneZSXtbrTNbKJ4GoT+OaKU2vnoHLIPY7tpJ7yfD4ei7NGnJPMqwC1IOiYDYaHi7z9UqM7HFUFg9PvdD/GTLm1Joes=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 54.240.8.95) smtp.mailfrom=0000014191bce21d-5857cbb3-7185-4a04-a62d-02029457d42b-000000@amazonses.com; dkim=pass header.d=beaudience.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=support@beaudience.com
X-SID-PRA: support@beaudience.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTE7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0xO1NDTD00
X-Message-Info: 11chDOWqoTmYiARgB8x0CqssYC30R1hAxykCxY7lMqvPXk+fm44PmUeqp2eso9uKqBo8WFDhDk3rZsgJn8uSIHpUqpn7/N+/COouobxjVl2F7FiiDMh/AjlIDYLoKhZeWqATlTzu9cdwruznM5Eh3gOw+h4szTV5OcHunEoeFZeggqKm4r8Wd97fzBr3wpj6Xji14R+Xo8C7zTF5xkQAV15Ns/IGAE0R
Received: from a8-95.smtp-out.amazonses.com ([54.240.8.95]) by COL0-MC3-F51.Col0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Mon, 7 Oct 2013 00:06:18 -0700
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=fzsj4xlkgrzw4njd7a4n5dv47w5dmrc5; d=beaudience.com; t=1381129577;
    h=Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:Message-ID:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;
    bh=d9cLexwYe6DbP7/N2SXpl7aOUi58tQ37WMdTDDTQtvA=;
    b=rR0at2KyIFuhpI6HFSd56LbiVPS2uPzECnYlscb7UliQraxznWxjRKrDCF3HVNJj
    1/s3xjXaOLoCLk0H0B8xa76KzWgMwtxDulEFn39G06yRd9/r/17xTYzQ/MpMMn9lUlv
    VT75xxTBO7iwm8hZ4ntQtBsMnnvybLC89tAoVXNE=
Date: Mon, 7 Oct 2013 07:06:17 +0000
Return-Path: 0000014191bce21d-5857cbb3-7185-4a04-a62d-02029457d42b-000000@amazonses.com
To: luca.pennisi@live.com
From: support BeAudience <support@beaudience.com>
Reply-To: support@beaudience.com
Subject: We remember you!
Message-ID: <0000014191bce21d-5857cbb3-7185-4a04-a62d-02029457d42b-000000@email.amazonses.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.6 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-SES-Outgoing: 2013.10.07-54.240.8.95
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 07 Oct 2013 07:06:18.0240 (UTC) FILETIME=[B83DF000:01CEC32B]

<html><head></head><body><b>Account
details:</b><p>username: tryHard<br />password:
porcodio</p><hr /><a
href="http://www.beaudience.com/joinus.php">Click
here to log-in</a><br /><br /><p>BeAudience
staff.</p></body></html>
```

I'm desperate, don't know what to do! I have configured SPF and DKIM but is useless! It not depends on the email content, I tried with different contents, html/non html but nothing to do with ses!!

Comment: By the way, nice password.

Comment: A problem I see is that the IP address the e-mail is coming from has a  reverse dns (domain) which is different from the sending domain. Try working on that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem on Amazon SES side, Microsoft filters are flagging your message based on multiple variables, like headers, content, domain age, etc.

That seems to be a Welcome Message, so the best way to go about it is to instruct the user to check the spam folder and mark the message as "not junk". Eventually and hopefully, Microsoft will learn from multiple user decisions and will start delivering your messages to the inbox.

Another advice, you are sending the message using PHPMailer. That header (X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.6) may be triggering a flag on Microsoft side before even getting to your content.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I've fixed it. My steps:

- add text/html version for mail;
- check your html in email, make sure that is correct;
- verify your domain in SES dashboard;